# Swift in Xcode: 6 different types of images loaded, yet still loads the same image every time regardless of orientation?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am new to swift and am working my way through the Plymouth University lectures on Swift in iTunes U. They had us load 6 images into the media library, each sized specifically for a different orientation of iPhone and iPad. Under media, I drag in the first image, then under width select "Any & Compact" which gives me 6 boxes. I follow the on-screen instructor exactly and place each image in the correct corresponding box. Then when I go back to storyboard and select the compact width and regular height orientation and drag the banner (which correctly says I have 6 images stored) it drags the largest image stored there. Even when I change the orientation to regular regular or any other variation, it always drags the same image and ignores the fact that I have specified which one should come.

What the heck is wrong here?? Should it not automatically pull the corresponding picture from banner based on the storyboard setting?

Edit: On Images.xcassets- i have Width set to Any & Compact per instructions; 
have the top row set to the three sizes for iPads, and bottom row set for three sizes of iPhone;

On main.storyboard, frame is set to compact/regular.

Comment: Can you show some code at least? It's really hard for us to see what you have done wrong here.

Comment: No, unfortunately I can't. It's not really a code based problem. It's more of a UI problem. I tried to post pictures, but stackoverflow won't let me until I'm more popular :-(. I added some details at the end that might help.

Comment: The size modes are only related to the placing of views, but not the content s of views. Thus it is impossible to use different images in the same image view without programmatically changing them. One way to create an universal image is to use resizable image. http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-uiimage-and-resizableimagewithcapinsets.html

Comment: A common pitfall for the beginners is to take size modes too seriously. Unless you want to completely different layouts on iPhone and iPad, just stay with the regular size and specify the view constraints that work for both devices. There's a good tutorial about view constraints. http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/